# iOS How to print NSLOG for c++ variable (2d vector array)?

Tags: c++, ios, iphone, swift

I have something with type

```
typedef vector<long,2> point;
```

As my custom vector type;

written inside Obj-c .m file

But cant print it with NSlog , Obj-c

Howto access  p.x and p.y ???

Thanks

Comment: To avoid confusion, you should clarify that this is your own `vector` type, not the standard one.

Comment: How is this related to Swift???

Comment: my App combined triple langs  (C++ , Obj-c , Swift )  C++ for low level external library.

Answer (score 0):

Vector is a dynamic array pattern.
So, you created an array type with 2 'long' elements.

You can use it to define an instance.
e.g.
`point mypoint;`

To retrieve an item use `mypoint.at(0)` and `mypoint.at(1)`

Comment: i got this error    Type 'xx::point' (aka 'vector<long,2> does not provide a subscript operator

Comment: @ddwdwwfdrewret fixed